# error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfc100d.lib'

Tags: visual-studio, opencv3.0

I compiled program that made for VS 2010 in VS 2013, I got this error.
I did change the tool to VS 2010 (V100) and add dependencies (both mfc100d.lib and mfc120d.lib).

I also set project defaults > Use of MFC > Use MFC in Shared DLL.
I'm trying to looking for mfc100d.lib but can't find that on my computer, I just have mfc100d.dll.

Do anyone has reference to related website, so I can download mfc100d.lib?

this is my error:

```
error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfc100d.lib'
```

I use OpenCV 3.0 and VS Ultimate 2013.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: I have worked project in VS 2010.
After upgrading to VS 2013.
I have faced the same issue.

Comment: I have checked all dependency in source files & All dependency has pointed to VS 2013. 
After that, I have ignored mfc100d.lib & mfcs100.lib in VS 2013.
How to ignore those files?
Go to: Project Properties --> Linker --> Input --> Ignore Specific Default Libraries
I hope, Your solution will be resolved.